# GCM message launching an Intent

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Right now I am creating a notification intent as per the following:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
notificationIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

notificationIntent.putExtra("key", value);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification updateComplete = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setTicker(title)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notifications)
    .build();

notificationManager.notify(100, updateComplete);
```

When the app is already in the background, everything works. The function `onNewIntent` is called and I get the value from the notificationIntent extras. However, if the app is NOT in the background, it goes to the root activity (login screen) which forwards the user to `MyActivity`. But the root activity doesn't get the call to `onNewIntent`, and by the time the user gets to `MyActivity`, the extras are lost.

Is there anyway around this?

I have been trying to store values elsewhere to no avail... This includes shared preferences.

Comment: kvish have you can check if application is ruuning or not?if application running then no need to notification intent extra .right?

Comment: Reason I need the notificationIntent is because I have some data that needs to be passed to that `Activity`. Otherwise, how will I know if the user has pressed the push notification or not? I want to be able to extract some data from the push and show the relevant information...is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this.

Basically, if the activity you are launching with `notificationIntent` is already open (if it's the current activity the user is on), it will call `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`. If it is not currently the active activity or if the application is not running, it will launch the activity and go to `onCreate()`.

You have to get the intent from `onCreate()` by calling `getIntent()` and checking to see it's not null. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(final Context ctx, Intent intent) {
if (CommonMethod.isAppicationRunning(ctx)) {
            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ctx, ViewMessageDialog.class);
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            resultIntent.putExtra("gcmmessage", message);
            ctx.startActivity(resultIntent);
        } else {

            try {
                sendNotification(message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public static boolean isAppicationRunning(Context activity) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) activity
                .getSystemService(EGLifeStyleApplication.mContext.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // get the info from the currently running task
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        Log.i("current activity", "activity"
                + activity.getClass().getSimpleName());

        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(
                EGLifeStyleApplication.mContext.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
private void sendNotification(String message) throws JSONException {
        // this
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.app_icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = message; // ticker-text
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        context.getClass().getSimpleName();
        Log.i("context.getClass().getSimpleName()",
                "context.getClass().getSimpleName()="
                        + context.getClass().getSimpleName());

        CharSequence contentTitle = "Product Received.";
        CharSequence contentText = message;
        Intent notificationIntent = null;
        int notificationID = CommonVariable.notificationID;

        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ViewHomeScreen.class);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
    }
```

check app running or not?if app is running in forgroung then please call only intent to pass that specific activity.and if app is running in backgroung then call sendnotification() to send notification on notification bar.

Comment: My question is more around this: `notificationIntent.putExtra("key", value);`, I need the value when the application is opened by clicking on the push notification. When the app is already open (or in background) it works, but when the app is not running, that value is lost... I'm seeing the notification in the notification bar, i'm just not seeing the value from the `extras` for the intent.

Comment: you can use broadcast receiver    then your value can not be lost

Answer (score 1):

//this code is put in your gcmservice

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent();
                intent2.setAction("RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION_NEW");
                intent2.putExtra("senderNum", senderNum);
                intent2.putExtra("verificationCode",
                        ReturnValidationcode(message));
                context.sendBroadcast(intent2);
```

Comment: Not sure if I get this...reading up on the `sendBroadcast`, but is this for the notificationIntent I wrote about above?

Comment: Is it possible to send the broadcast only when the notification is clicked on?

Comment: i don't know exectly.but when you don't handle broadcasr receiver when        you will already in your app.when your app in your background then notification arrives and broadcast calls.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) out. I don't know why your activity should run to get the upadate. If you follow that tutorial, then the mobile will automatically get push notification, if there are any. No need to run activity on background.

Comment: It's not that I can't get the notification. The notification has some data in it that I need to extract... That's the issue i'm facing. Which is why I need the `onNewIntent` function called